# Check if string column last characters are numbers in Pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe:

```
   Code               Mark
0  Abd 43212312312   
1  Charles de Gaulle
2  Carlitos 4132411  
3  Antonio
```

If the last 5 characters of the string in the Code column are numbers, I want that 'Mark' is 'A', so it will look like this:

```
   Code               Mark
0  Abd 43212312312    A
1  Charles de Gaulle
2  Carlitos 4132411   A
3  Antonio
```

I'm trying to use [isnumeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html) but I'm constantly getting AttributeError: `'Series' object has no attribute 'isnumeric'`

Can someone help on that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are close. The trick is to use the `.str` accessor via [`pd.Series.str.isnumeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html).

Then map to 'A' or an empty string via `pd.Series.map`:

```
df['Mark'] = df['Code'].str[-5:]\
                       .str.isnumeric()\
                       .map({True: 'A', False: ''})

print(df)

              Code Mark
0   Abd43212312312    A
1  CharlesdeGaulle     
2  Carlitos4132411    A
3          Antonio
```

Comment: Very clever, I imagine this would be faster than `pd.Series.str.match`?

Comment: @Tim, I expect this to be more efficient than a regular expression. But would always test with your data set and consider alternatives, e.g. a list comprehension is often quicker than `pd.Series.str` methods.

Answer (score 4):

Using [`pd.Series.str.match`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.match.html), you can use

```
import numpy as np

df['Mark'] = np.where(df.Code.str.match(r'.*?\d{5}$'), 'A', '')
```

Note that `'.*?`' is a non-greedy regex match, `'\d{5}'` checks for 5 digits, and `'$'` matches a string end.